# Postgres DB Column Type Conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, migration

Trying to convert a string column to date. Column currently holds values, such as '20170130', and '20161130'.

When I try:

```
change_column :tickets, :string_date, :date
```

This gives me an error:

> ```
> PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "string_date" cannot be cast automatically to type date. 
> HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
> ```

So, I try:

```
change_column :tickets, :string_date, 'date USING CAST(string_date AS date)'
```

Still no luck, with the following error:

> PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date

Anyone know what's going on?? Thought converting from string to date would be easier...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strange - I would expect to see the value, where you fail to cast date, eg:

```
t=# create table a2(string_date text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into a2 values ('20170130'),('20161130');
INSERT 0 2
t=# insert into a2 select 'bad value';
INSERT 0 1
t=# alter table a2 alter COLUMN string_date type date using string_date::date;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "bad value"
```

maybe its an empty string?..

anyway - find bad value and fix it, then try to  convert again:

```
t=# select string_date from a2 where string_date !~ '\d{8}';
 string_date
-------------
 bad value
(1 row)
t=# begin;
BEGIN
t=# delete from a2 where string_date !~ '\d{8}';
DELETE 1
t=# alter table a2 alter COLUMN string_date type date using string_date::date;
ALTER TABLE
t=# end;
COMMIT
```

Comment: this helped me a lot! Thanks! it turns out there was a bad record (bah, can't believe I didn't notice it before). I removed the bad record, and boom, there it goes! Thanks!